# How do I create a selector for something adjacent to an id?

Tags: css

I need to add a selector in css to bold the paragraph adjacent to the goals_container id.

Html code looks like:

```
<body>
    <main>
        <div id="goals_container">
        </div>
        <p> This is what I want to access </p>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: What have you tried ? This is extremely simple CSS 101 type of stuff, and sounds like homework

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`+` (adjacent sibling)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) selector:

```css
#goals_container + p {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <div id="goals_container">
        </div>
        <p> This is what I want to access </p>
    </main>
</body>
```